# How to make downloaded file visible in Gallery in Android Q?

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-storage, scoped-storage

I am using download manager to download file like so:

```
   DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
    request.setTitle(createTitle());
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(activity, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, subFolders + createFileName());
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
```

After it is downloaded, I am adding it to the media store like so:

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    ContentResolver database = activity.getContentResolver();

                    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName);
                    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.MIME_TYPE, mimeType);
                    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/subfolder");
                    database.insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
                }
```

I will see the folder created in the gallery but the file always shows up as corrupted.
Can anyone help ?

Comment: As a test do not add to the gallery but check if the file is downloaded correctly. The subfolder should already have been created before or during download. (And not by the media store). Is the file created? What is its file size?

Comment: If the download manager does its work correctly there should be no neef to add your file to the media store i think. And after a reboot of your device the media store should index your file automatically.

Comment: database.insert() will return an uri for a new file. You are doing nothing with that uri.

Comment: @blackapps with download manager the file is within internal storage. How is it possible to view that file within the gallery?

Comment: @blackapps yes the folder is created.

Comment: `with download manager the file is within internal storage. `. How do you know? How did you check that? And under which path exactly?

Comment: @blackapps  I am using the file manager and see the file. Inside DownloadManager request I am using setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(activity, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, subFolders)

Comment: I knew that already because it is in your code. But i asked you to tell the full path. You didn't.

Comment: Further try to open your file using the file manager (before you add to media store). Is it corrupted? About which 'the file manager' are you talking?

Comment: @blackappsthis gives me the path of `storage/emulated/0/Download/custom/programs/filename.png`

Comment: `About which 'the file manager' are you talking? –` On Android Q?

Comment: @blackapps It is not corrupted when I open it using file manager and I am using the `files` app that comes with the Google Pixel 3_XL emulator.  In the gallery I can see the folder but the actual file is corrupted and wont open.

Comment: The Files app on my Google Pixel 3 XL emulator does not give classic file paths (like /storage/emulated/....) but content schemes.

Comment: `contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/subfolder");` That does not match `/storage/emulated/0/Download/custom/programs/filename.png`.

Comment: @blackapps how could I get it to match? I was editing my code so it would instead be `contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/custom/programs/[filename]");`

Comment: `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(activity, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, subFolders + createFileName());` That can never lead to `/storage/emulated/0/Download/custom/programs/filename.png`. Instead it would lead to `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/Download/custom/programs/filename.png`. Please clarify. Also clarify why you did not react on my comment concerning the Files app. Please communicate better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208087/discussion-between-androidlearner-and-blackapps).

Comment: @blackapps I sent you messages in the discussion

Comment: Sorry. No chatting. Clarify all here.

Comment: So the path that I am saving to storage/emulated/0/Android/data/[packageName]/files/Download/custom/programs/
I thought I did. I am using the stock Files app that is available in Android Pixel 3 XL emulator. It has a blue icon.

Comment: In the Download Manager Request I am using             request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(activity, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, subfolders) where subfolders is = `custom/programs/` @blackapps

Answer (score 2):

To be able to load or view your downloaded image in gallery you need to scan the saved file using MediaScannerConnection:

```
private void scanFile(String path) {

    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
            new String[] { path }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.d("Tag", "Scan finished. You can view the image in the gallery now.");
                }
            });
}
```

Call this after you create your file path or in your checking if the file does exist:

```
scanFile(filePath);
```

Hope it will work :)